# How to get the index and value of a dynamic json newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting a json which has a status property which is an array of objects, the problem is that both the index and the value of each object have dynamic values ​​and I need to iterate that array to get both values. How can I do this?

**My data:**

```
"estatus": [
   {"xa654": "Success"}, 
   {"91823d": "Warning"}, 
   {"23sgf65": "Procesing"}, 
   {"cvb875": "Success"}
]
```

**My actual code:**

```
json = JObject.Parse(jsonParam);
JArray arrProyectos = (JArray)json["estatus"];
int arrProyectosLength = arrProyectos.Count;
foreach (var data in json)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate `JArray` instead of `JObject` like this:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonParam);
JArray arrProyectos = (JArray)json["estatus"];
int arrProyectosLength = arrProyectos.Count;
foreach (var data in arrProyectos)
{
    //You can get name as following:
    var name = ((JProperty)data.First).Name.ToString();

    //You can get value as following:
    var value = ((JProperty)data.First).Value.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I needed, I will review what other things I can do with JProperty, thank you very much!